# Java 9 plugin from marketplace stuck at requirements calculation

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-marketplace

When I try to install Java 9 support plugin for latest Eclipse Oxygen from Eclipse Marketplace it stops on "Calculating requirements and dependencies" step. I have completely fresh instance of Eclipse (JEE package) and both, Java 8 and 9 installed.

When I revealed "sleeping" taks in progress area I found that it stops on this step (marked with red rectangle):

[image]

I tried few suggestions found over internet:

- Disable firewall (windows built in and on the router side) and windows defender
- Disable "Contact all update sites... option from "Install new Software" window"
- run eclipse with vm parameter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
- even tried to install this while running at Windows Safe Mode
- Changed Preferences -> General -> Network connections settings
- Install packages manually by "Install new software" window instead directly from MarketPlace

None of them helped so far. Furthermore, when entered given url into web browser window, I was able to download content.jar. This entry comes as software source only when I try to install Java 9 support. It was not present on the software sources list and enables automatically every time I retry plugin installation.

Has anyone faced similar problem and knows how to solve it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe, this is Off-topic here. This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center

Comment: @nullpointer Questions about programming tools such as Eclipse are on topic

Comment: If you can aford to wait until October 11 there will be a complete Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) release with the full Java 9 support.

Comment: I can, this is not a problem. I am just curious why I cant install this on windows and how to avoid possible problem in future. I guess that someone uses that on windows. I tried the same with Linux version of eclipse and it did fine. Additionally, it did not extend software source list with source url visible on screenshot.

Comment: Maybe an unavailable update site is the problem: try to disable some (_Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Update Sites_). You can [download release candidates of Oxygen.1a here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php).

Comment: Is there anything relevant in Eclipse's Error Log? Messages relating to plugin problems can often be found there.

Comment: Actually it does throw SocketException after some time. Here it is https://pastebin.ca/3882549

Comment: Normally, such downloads should be redirected to a mirror. Seeing that it insisted in contacting the original at download.eclipse.org could be one part of the problem. The other part could just be very heavy traffic on that server during a season of lots of releases (Oxygen.1, Java Support, release candidates for Oxygen.1a etc.). Does retrying on another day show the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried on separate instance today and it always dies on that particular url. What is weird, I tried same on different computer in my home network and it failed with same reason, but on pc in different ISP it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Invader92 ***Update as of 11 October,2017*** - You shall upgrade to the latest [eclipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which is marked as released and supports Java 9.

Comment: Indeed I did, yet my original problem still remains (any plugin installation, see answer below). Anyway, I let it go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution to my problem was to disable apache http client, described here: [Disable Apache HttpClient](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient).

It allowed me to go forward and install any plugin from Marketplace (actually Java9 plugin was only just one of many due to that "corrupted" URL.

I would not treat that as a permanent solution, cause I still don't know why default configuration is not working properly, but I can move on.